# Facebook.com redirecting to SearchMagnified.com

Tags: chromium, browser, malware

Please need urgent help.I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and using chromium browser latest build.When ever I go for facebook.com on my browser it redirecting me to SearchMagnified.com. This issue is found only in Google chrome browser.

Any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some "malware/spamish" plugin installed in chrome.
check for plugins that look suspicious and disable/uninstall them.

Comment: It's a well-known malware apparently.  Does it really show up as a plugin?  My impression was that it does not.